# MySQL different explain plan for the same query

Tags: mysql, optimization, explain

I've got the following query that performs well locally (0.4 execution time which is acceptable):

```
SELECT categories.*, parameters_values.key, l.* FROM categories
JOIN parameters_values ON parameters_values.parameter_id = 2 AND parameters_values.country_id = 223
JOIN categories_countries ON categories.category_id = categories_countries.category_id AND categories_countries.country_id = 223
JOIN listings AS l ON l.listing_id = (
    SELECT listings.listing_id FROM listings
    JOIN listings_categories ON listings.listing_id = listings_categories.listing_id
    JOIN categories AS c ON listings_categories.category_id = c.category_id
    WHERE
    (c.category_id = categories.category_id OR c.subcategory = categories.category_id) AND
    CASE parameters_values.`key`
        WHEN 1 THEN listings.transaction_type = 1 OR listings.transaction_type = 3
        WHEN 2 THEN listings.transaction_type = 2 OR listings.transaction_type = 3
        WHEN 3 THEN true
    END AND
    listings.country_id = 223 AND
    listings.property_type = 1 AND
    listings.active = 1 AND
    listings.published_flag = 1 AND
    st_intersects(
    POINT(listings.lng, listings.lat),
    (SELECT IFNULL(`l`.`polygon`, GET_SQUARE(`l`.`lat`, `l`.`lng`, `l`.`radius`, `l`.`country_id`)) 
    FROM `locations` AS `l` WHERE `location_id` = 1 LIMIT 1)
    )

    LIMIT 1
) ORDER BY categories.subcategory, categories.`order`
```

It simply checks for existence of listings in a category, there is a location search in there, nothing overly complicated. The execution plan locally looks as follows:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                          | key                                     | key_len | ref                                 | rows | Extra                                          |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | parameters_values    | ref    | parameter_id,country_id                                                                                                                | parameter_id                            | 8       | const,const                         |    3 | Using temporary; Using filesort                |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | categories_countries | ref    | PRIMARY,categories_countries_country_id_foreign                                                                                        | categories_countries_country_id_foreign | 4       | const                               |  122 | Using index                                    |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | categories           | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | cp.categories_countries.category_id |    1 | NULL                                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | l                    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,listings_listing_id_transaction_type                                                                                           | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | func                                |    1 | Using where                                    |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c                    | ALL    | PRIMARY,categories_subcategory_foreign                                                                                                 | NULL                                    | NULL    | NULL                                |  127 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x5) |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | listings_categories  | ref    | PRIMARY,listings_categories_category_id_foreign                                                                                        | listings_categories_category_id_foreign | 4       | cp.c.category_id                    |  273 | Using index                                    |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | listings             | eq_ref | PRIMARY,listings_country_id_foreign,listings_country_created_at,listings_country_units_created_at,listings_listing_id_transaction_type | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | cp.listings_categories.listing_id   |    1 | Using where                                    |
|  3 | SUBQUERY           | l                    | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | const                               |    1 | NULL                                           |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+
```

However the query appears to be executed differently on the server as the last four rows are following:

```
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | listings             | ref    | PRIMARY,listings_country_id_foreign,listings_country_created_at,listings_country_units_created_at,listings_listing_id_transaction_type | listings_country_id_foreign             | 4       | const                               | 18238 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | listings_categories  | ref    | PRIMARY,listings_categories_category_id_foreign                                                                                        | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | cp.listings.listing_id              |     1 | Using index                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | c                    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,categories_subcategory_foreign                                                                                                 | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | cp.listings_categories.category_id  |     1 | Using where                     |
|  3 | SUBQUERY           | l                    | const  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                | PRIMARY                                 | 4       | const                               |     1 | NULL                            |
+----+--------------------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------+-------+---------------------------------+
```

Funny enough the search with the former plan with no use of key performs very well, the latter however takes about 23 seconds to execute. How could I tell MySQL to follow the same execution plan?

Comment: Did you recently add the ORDER BY clause?  That will typically slow up a query, especially if a limit is applied, it still has to get all qualified records, order them, then return only those within a specified limit.

Comment: The exact same query is executed on two servers, as you can see the slower one has a few more indexes but other than that everything seems identical. Perhaps ignoring the indexes in the join would force mysql to execute the same query plan?

Comment: The query optimizer looks at the cardinality of the indexes to decide which would be best to use. If the data distribution on the two servers are different, it will affect the query plan.